# Is there a way to disable date input method inside google material date picker

Tags: android, material-design

"i'm using google's material date picker 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10' version,and i want to disable the input method through keyboard,is there a way to disable/hide the edit method"

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea, as it will hurt accessibility. Not everyone can use the calendar method.

Comment: Any success? I also want to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 14):

you can use custom style as workaround to disable calendar input mode toggle. This toggle uses style attribute materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton, so:

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.MaterialDatePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
<item name="materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton">@style/Widget.AppTheme.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton</item>
```

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton">
<item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
```

And after that apply theme with:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    .setTheme(R.style.Widget_AppTheme_MaterialDatePicker)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access PickerDialogs View and then make this button Gone but make sure to wait for the dialogs view to initialize first by adding this line after `dialog.show` method

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.executePendingTransactions()
```

then

```
(picker.view?.findViewById(R.id.mtrl_picker_header_toggle) as View).visibility = View.GONE
```